# JavaScript throws TypeError saying that my variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I don't have much experience in JavaScript, so far I have this:

```
  function loop() {
    var authorDivs = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_MCPObjectInfo_dvCreatorView').getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i = 0; i < authorDivs.length; i++) {
        var divOfDiv = authorDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");

        if (typeof divOfDiv.item(i) === 'undefined' || divOfDiv.item(i) === null) {
            console.log("This is undefined or null");
        }
        else {
            var realDivs = divOfDiv.item(i);
            realDivs.item(i).textContent = "please work plz";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error from the console in FireFox: `TypeError: realDivs is undefined` on this line: `realDivs.item(i).innerHTML = "please work plz";`

Essentially what I have (in my mind) is a loop that goes through `authorDivs` and gets all of the `divs` within those `divs` and saves them in `divOfDiv`. I then check to see if the `divs` in `divOfDiv` are `undefined` or `null`, if they are **not** then those `divs` get saved in a variable `realDivs` which I then use to edit the innerHTML. That's what I'd ideally like to see happen, what is causing the error? What am I doing wrong?

Note: I do not have access to jQuery but only JavaScript.

Edit: I've added the changes suggested below and its fixed that -- thanks! But I'm now getting the following error: `TypeError: realDivs.item is not a function`

What is causing that? And on another note how do I know when I'm dealing with an array and when I'm dealing with an HTMLCollection? Do you just assume? I've never used a loosely typed language before so its new to me.

Comment: You're only assigning `realDivs` in the `else` clause then using it outside the `if`. What do you expect?

Comment: Debug and step through your code one line at a time as it executes and inspect your variables and objects. This is how you'll find out what's wrong.

Comment: `|| 'null'` is very wrong.

Comment: Okay I've added those changes, and like I said I'm very new... trying my best. I've gone through the code line by line but its hard to pick up what's wrong when you don't necessarily know what's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'll need to move that code inside the conditional block that is supposed to prevent it! Also, `|| "null"` is not going to work as you expect, you'll need to check for `|| divOfDiv.item(i) === null` explicitly.

So try

```
for (var i = 0; i < authorDivs.length; i++) {
    var divOfDiv = authorDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");

    if (divOfDiv.item(i) == null) {
        console.log("This is undefined or null");
    } else {
        var realDivs = divOfDiv.item(i)
        realDivs.item(i).innerHTML = "please work plz";
        console.log(divOfDiv.item(i));
    }
}
```

However, that still doesn't really work for two reasons:

- The `i` index you use to access the `i`-th `divOfDiv` comes from the iteration over `authorDivs` - hardly what you want. Instead, use a second loop over all `divOfDiv`s.
- Your `realDivs` variable does hold a single `<div>`, which does not have an `.item` method. You'd just directly access its `.innerHTML` property.

So you should use

```
var authorDivs = document.getElementById('authorView').getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0; i<authorDivs.length; i++) {
    var divsOfDiv = authorDivs.item(i).getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var j=0; j<divsOfDiv.length; j++) {
        var realDiv = divsOfDiv.item(j);
        realDiv.innerHTML = "please work plz";
        console.log(realDiv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it will happen in case when your `if (typeof divOfDiv.item(i) === 'undefined' || 'null')` returns true. Then you never initialize `realDivs` (what would happen if condition was falsy). Later you try to call `item` function on that unitialized object

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code.

1. comparing DOM object with 'undefined' and null. If div tag is not available in authorDivs[i], it will return empty DOM array. So, comparision of empty DOM array with undefined and null is not good approach. We can use array length property for doing validation.

   divOfDiv = authorDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
   if(divOfDiv.length > 0) { console statement}
2. As item(i) is already return single DOM element, item(i) of "realDivs" variable is not proper approach. In addition to this, innerHTML method needs to be used after validating whether realDivs contains DOM element. Please update the code as below.

   var realDivs = divOfDiv.item(i);
    realDivs ? (realDivs.innerHTML = "please work plz"): null;

Note : item(i) will return null if DOM is not available.